# Sharepoint Online list - display future dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sharepoint-online, date

I would like to **display the date (dd-mm-yyyy) of the first day of the next quarter** in a column (call it *Due Date*).

This would not be calculated based on any other date entry in the Sharepoint Online list, just **based upon the current system date**.

E.g. for today (3/24/2020) the Due Date would display 4/1/2020.  When 4/1/2020 arrives the *Due Date* field would automatically be updated to 7/1/2020 and display as such until 7/1/2020 arrives...etc. etc.

What would be the appropriate formula to enter when creating the new column?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot base formulas on the current date unless you use a workflow or Flow to update every item every day.  Formulas only calculate at the time an item is modified, so it prohibits references to functions like `today` and `now`.  You might be able to trick it by using a JSON column formatter to display a calculated date based on the current day, but this won't actually change the underlying value in the field.

Answer (score 1):

Formula will not be able to do so just like Willman said. The only doable approach will be using a flow which will run repeatedly everyday to update the due date column. There is a trigger called [recurrence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks) which can run the flow on a certain time period.